# Looking For HaMaspik

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, rambam, rishonim

I am looking for the halachic portion of Hamaspik L'ovdey Hashem by R. Avraham Ben HaRambam published by Bar Ilan Univ. I have found links to it on HebrewBooks, but it isnt there (I guess it was taken down). Does anyone know where it can be found for free online or the most inexpensively. Perhaps someone dowloaded it from HebrewBooks before it was removed?

Comment: There's are excerpts [here](http://live.shofar.tv/articles/print/5309) and [here](http://live.shofar.tv/articles/print/5308), for what it's worth.

Comment: I bought a used one for 5 shekels somewhere in Meah Shearim once upon a time.

Comment: @DoubleAA the halachic section?

Comment: @mevaqesh Don't know. It's basically just been sitting on my shelf.

Comment: @mevaqesh Translated by Yosef ben Tzalach Dori, 5733, published by Keren Hotzaat Sifrei Rabbanei Bavel. 2nd ed. Hebrew. Is that a good edition? I'm not particularly interested in selling it.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure. different portions have been found and translated separately. I believe that for the ethical section, the best translation into any language in Wincellberg's Feldheim English translation, while for the halakhic portion, the only translation in the Bar Ilan Dana translation. I suspect that your is an edition of the ethical portion.

Comment: @mevaqesh does Wincellberg's translation not include the halakhic portion? Is there a reason why it isn't included, or just that it doesn't fit the model for the Feldheim series?

Comment: @Chaim probably because the felheim version was meant to be part of their mussar series so they didnt add that plus its harder to get your hands on the 2nd manuscript than the one he published

Comment: i have the better version by yosef ben salah dori but im not gonna link that here

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov thats fine. im just curious: is that also a translation of the halakhic portion that dana did?

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov why won't you post the "better version" by yosef ben salah dori?

Comment: @mevaqesh i looked inside and its both published by feldheim and both have the assistance or r wincelberg. its the mussar version unfortunately. i thought someone else did a translation on that manuscript besides dana maybe im mistaken

Comment: @Chaim reasons i wont go into

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here you go:

http://www.docdroid.net/rko0/kefayet.pdf.html

and a review by a scholar you should be sure to read:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqlRjI2RERad3haakU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A thousand thanks I would give more upvotes if I could. Do you know by any chance why it was removed from HB. E.g. if there are copyright issues...I just want to make sure this is כשר וישר.

Comment: no clue. but once it was made public and people downloaded it, you cant say give it back lol....

Comment: mori qafih zl did not like dana's translation many things. he called him an am ho oras for thinking a jamaro quoted by a book is arabic and trying to translate it without knowing it is a jamaro. this is why i linked the review by prof yinon fenton. he also states dana's translations are not accurate many times but he praises him for trying with this. dont take the entire work at face value and read the review where the prof fixes the inaccuracies of dana.

Comment: Very good to know. Nevertheless there is no other translation as of now...

Comment: @mevaqesh yes and unfortunately there are not many people alive with the arabic skills of mori qafih zl to translate judeo arabic into hebrew. i doubt there will be another printing of this by someone else. i hope my words are not true

Comment: Rav Shilat is pretty fluent with judeo arabic

Comment: @Efraim whos that

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA

Comment: @Efraim apparently he is not a native judeo arabic speaker. his father is ashkanazi and he isnt in the linguist field like for example prof blau. knowing judeo arabic is not the same as being fluent like mori qafih zl.

Comment: Don't judge until you read his material, (ad hominem argument)

Comment: See also this link https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A5